# On characterizations for near-square primes and Fermat primes in terms of equations involving arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum, fermat-numbers

In this post we denote the Euler's totient function that counts the number of positive integers $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $\gcd(k,n)=1$ as $\varphi(n)$, and the sum of divisors function $\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ as $\sigma(n)$.

We propose the first conjecture inspired in the form of near-square primes, that are the primes of the form $n^2+1$ corresponding to the sequence *A002496* from the OEIS, and the second conjecture from the form of the primes $2^{2^n}+1$, that are the known as Fermat primes *A019434* from the OEIS. As general reference I add the Wikipedia articles related to [*Landau's problems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems#Near-square_primes) and for [*Fermat number.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number)

**Conjecture 1.** *Let* $x> 1$ *be an integer for which there exists a positive integer* $y\geq 1$ *such that the identity*
$$y^{x-1-\sigma(x)}=\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\tag{1}$$
*holds, then* $x$ *is a near-square prime.*

As remark notice that we exclude the (input) case $x=1$ that corresponds to $x=0^2+1$, that is the specialization of $n^2+1$ for $n=0$, an integer that isn't a prime number.

**Conjecture 2.** *Let* $x\geq 1$ *be an integer for which there exists a positive integer* $y\geq 1$ *such that the identity*
$$-(\sigma(x)-x+1)^y=\log_2\left(\frac{1}{\varphi(x)}\right)\tag{2}$$
*holds, then* $x$ *is a Fermat prime greater than* $3$.

As remark the equation $(2)$ excludes (as output) the first Fermat prime that corresponds to the specialization of $2^{2^n}+1$ for $n=0$.

> **Question.** What work can be done with the purpose to prove or refute previous conjectures? Can you find counterexamples? **Many thanks.**

**Computational experiments.**  You can check in the web *Sage Cell Server* this (or similar ones) line written in Pari/GP

`for(x=2, 10000, for(y=1, 100, if(y^(x-1-sigma(x))==1/eulerphi(x),print(x," ",y))))`

just copy and paste it to evaluate in the web choosing as Language the option *GP*.

And for the second of our conjectures we've the following or similar

`for(x=1, 10000, for(y=1, 100, if((sigma(x)-x+1)^y==log(eulerphi(x))/log(2),print(x," ",y))))`

Comment: If some user is interesting we've the recent questions as posts of this site, MSE **3578715** and  reference MSE  **3587159**

Comment: I wrote other variants (for near-squares primes and Fermat primes) using a combination of the Euler's totient function and the Dedekind psi function, and since I hope that there aren't counterexamples for our conjectures of this post I am going to avoid ask about these that I evoke. But I would like to know if we can find counterxamples for **Conjceture 1** and **Conjecture 2.** Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two conjectures are true.

---

Conjecture 1 is true.

*Proof* :

$(1)$ is equivalent to 
$$y^{\sigma(x)-x+1}=\varphi(x)$$

Suppose that $x$ is a composite number. Then, there exists a divisor $d$ of $x$ such that $\sqrt x\le d\lt x$, so we get $\sigma(x)\ge 1+\sqrt x+x$. So, we have
$$\varphi(x)=y^{\sigma(x)-x+1}\ge 2^{\sqrt x+2}$$
Here, let us prove that $2^{\sqrt x+2}\gt x$ for $x\gt 1$.

Let $f(x)=2^{\sqrt x+2}-x$. Then, we have $f'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt x}$ where $g(x)=2^{\sqrt x+1}\ln 2-\sqrt x$. We have $g'(x)=\frac{h(x)}{2\sqrt x}$ where $h(x)=2^{\sqrt x+1}(\ln 2)^2-1$. Since $h(x)$ is increasing with $h(1)=\ln(4e)\ln(\frac 4e)\gt 0$, we get $h(x)\gt 0$ from which $g'(x)\gt 0$ follows with $g(1)=\ln\frac{16}{e}\gt 0$. Since $g(x)\gt 0$, we see that $f'(x)\gt 0$ with $f(1)=7\gt 0$ from which $f(x)\gt 0$ follows.$\quad\square$

So, we get
$$\varphi(x)=y^{\sigma(x)-x+1}\ge 2^{\sqrt x+2}\gt x\gt \varphi(x)$$
which is impossible.

So, $x$ has to be a prime number, and we get $y^{2}=x-1$.

It follows that $x$ has to be a near-square prime.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

Conjecture 2 is true.

*Proof* :

$(2)$ is equivalent to
$$(\sigma(x)-x+1)^y=\log_2\varphi(x)$$
The LHS is a positive integer, so there has to be a positive integer $k$ such that $\varphi(x)=2^k$. So, we see that $x$ has to be either of the form $x=2^m$ or of the form
$$x=2^m\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)$$
where $2^{a_1}+1,2^{a_2}+1,\cdots, 2^{a_n}+1$ are distinct primes.

In the former, we get
$$(2^{m})^y=m-1$$
which is impossible since the LHS is larger than the RHS.

In the latter, suppose that $m\ge 1$. Then, we have
$$\begin{align}m-1+a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n&=\bigg(1+(2^{m+1}-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+2)-2^m\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)\bigg)^y
\\\\&\gt (2^{m+1}-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+2)-2^m\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)
\\\\&\gt (2^{m+1}-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)-2^m\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)
\\\\&= (2^m-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)\end{align}$$
from which we have
$$m-1+a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n\gt (2^m-1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)$$
which is impossible. So, we have to have $m=0$.

Suppose that $n\ge 2$. Then, we have
$$\begin{align}a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n&=\bigg(1+\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+2)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)\bigg)^y
\\\\&\gt \prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1+1)-\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)
\\\\&\gt \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)\end{align}$$
from which we have
$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\gt \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2^{a_i}+1)$$
which is impossible. So, we have to have $n=1$.

So, we have to have $x=2^{a_1}+1$ and $2^y=a_1$.

It follows that $x$ has to be a Fermat prime greater than $3$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: Many thanks, I'm going to study your proposition. I would like to dedicate your result that proves **Conjecture 2** to your excellence: to yours excellent mathematics in this site.

Comment: @user759001: You are welcome. I've just added a proof that Conjecture 1 is true.

Comment: Now are your results, congratullations to prove these. In few days I'm going to award the bounty.